# How do I iterate through an inline var using pug

Tags: javascript, pug

I am attempting to iterate through an array and each time add 1 to the inline pug variable. So far this is what I got.

```
ul(class="benchcards")
            - var i = -1
            each card in cards
                -var L = i + 1
                li
                    a.btn(href="/addmonster" + L)
                        div=card.name
                        div= "Attack: "+card.attack
                        div= "HP: "+card.hp
                        div= "Attribute: "+card.attribute
                        div= "Energy: "+card.energy
```

When I run the page "L" is always = to 0. I want it to add 1 each time.
The question really comes down to what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You never increment `i`.

Comment: Barmar is correct. It would be better to use -var i = i + 1 rather than L= i + 1.

Comment: @DonaldKoscheka I've implemented your suggestion and it comes back as "addmonsterNaN"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments you are not incrementing the `i`, you can fix your issue like this:

```pug
ul.benchcards
  - var i = -1;
  each card in cards
    li
      a.btn(href='/addmonster' + i++)
        div= card.name
        div= 'Attack: ' + card.attack
        div= 'HP: ' + card.hp
        div= 'Attribute: ' + card.attribute
        div= 'Energy: ' + card.energy
```

Comment: Is it standard practice to edit an answer to paste in code from another answer?

Comment: Hi Sean, when I answered this, it was late for me, I was tired, just wanted to give a quick fix to OP, I didn't think much about the answer tbh, knowing I was going to improve it whenever I had the chance. Today when I was going to improve my answer I didn't expect to have 2 more answers to this question, but to your point I've been working with pug for the last 4/5 years till march, so I know about index in each loop  also I hate concatenation, preferring much more string templates/interpolation. In the end my improvements happened to match your answer, sorry if it seemed copy-paste.

Comment: At best this constitutes creating a duplicate of a preexisting answer, which shouldn't be done. If someone has already answered a question one way, you shouldn't edit or provide a new answer that's identical just because you'd do it the same way.

Comment: I've rolled back the edit, because it is literally character-for-character identical to Sean's.  While it may be a coincidence, Sean was indeed the first to propose that particular solution, and other answers shouldn't be edited to include that solution later.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use the [index built into the `each` iterator in Pug](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html#each). That way you don't have to declare or increment a variable.

```
ul.benchcards
  each card, i in cards
    li
      a.btn(href=`/addmonster${i}`)
        div #{card.name}
        div Attack: #{card.attack}
        div HP: #{card.hp}
        div Attribute: #{card.attribute}
        div Energy: #{card.energy}
```